# How to design a Cucumber-Selenium framework without using Static instances of the WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I am testing a web app using the Cucumber+Selenium framework. Currently, I am using static instances of the webdriver class to use the same driver instance in all the page/hooks classes. But I know that using static instances of the driver object is not a good practice. So my query is how can I achieve a good framework design without using Static instances of the driver. Your help will be very much appreciated.

Additional Info:

1. I am using Cucumber+Selenium.
2. I have a Base class, in which I have instantiated the WebDriver object.
3. All my page classes and hook/background classes are extending the Base class.

Comment: Is it based on Page object model ? Design pattern ?

Comment: Yes it is also based on page object model.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a way to share state between steps. And using a single static instance of a webdriver is not necessarily a bad way to do this.

However it also does mean you are sharing state between scenarios. This means that you have to clean the webdriver before each scenario. And any sharing of state between scenarios will prevent you from running scenarios in parallel.

To share state between steps, without sharing it between scenarios you can use dependency injection. For example with [cucumber-picocontainer](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/picocontainer).

```xml
<dependencies>
  [...]
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  [...]
</dependencies>
```

Cucumber can then inject step definitions with other objects. But because `WebDriver` is an interface you have to define a class without a constructor to use as a web driver.

```java
public class LazyWebDriver implements Webdriver, Disposable {

    private final Webdriver delegate;

    private Webdriver getDelegate() {
        if (delegate == null) {
            delegate = // create webdriver here
        } 
        return webdriver;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        if (webDriver == null) {
            return;
        }
        // Stop webdriver here
    }


    @Override
    public void someDelegatedMethod() {
        getDelegate().doSomeThing();
    }

    // more delegated methods here
   
   ...
}
```

Then you can inject the lazy webdriver into your steps:

```java
public class SomeStepDefinitions {

    private final WebDriver webDriver;

    SomeStepDefinitions(LazyWebDriver webDriver) {
        this.webDriver = webDriver;
    }

    // step definitions here
}
```

```java
public class SomeOtherStepDefinitions {

    private final WebDriver webDriver;

    SomeOtherStepDefinitions(LazyWebDriver webDriver) {
        this.webDriver = webDriver;
    }

    // step definitions here
}
```

Note that `Disposable` adds the dispose method which will let you clean up your driver a after each scenario.

http://picocontainer.com/lifecycle.html