# How to exclude the tags in spring boot test project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I have an automation test project which has both the API & GUI tests. It's been configured with Spring Boot annotation @SpringBootTest as below:

```
   @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes =           WebDriverConfiguration.class)
    @CucumberContextConfiguration
    public class SpringCucumberTest {

    }

    @Configuration
    @Scope(CucumberTestContext.SCOPE_CUCUMBER_GLUE)
    @ComponentScan("org.ki")
    public class WebDriverConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private WebDriverFactory webDriverFactory;

    @Scope(CucumberTestContext.SCOPE_CUCUMBER_GLUE)
    @Bean(initMethod = "", destroyMethod = "quit")
    public WebDriver webDriver() throws MalformedURLException {
        return webDriverFactory.createWebDriver();
    }
   }
```

Now the problem I'm facing is that the selenium webdriver is getting instantiated everytime irrespective of GUI or API test. My task is not to instantiate the webdriver instance if the test is API, we do have the tag in the cucumber feature file as @api.
Please advise. Thanks!

I would say I'm new to Spring framework but I have tried searching so many places but couldn't get it working even after adding custom annotations as below but none worked for me:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, TYPE, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@ExtendWith(ExcludeTagsCondition.class)
public @interface ExcludeTags {
String[] value();
}


    public class ExcludeTagsCondition implements ExecutionCondition {

    private static final ConditionEvaluationResult ENABLED_IF_EXCLUDE_TAG_IS_INVALID =
            ConditionEvaluationResult.enabled(
                    "@ExcludeTags does not have a valid tag to exclude, all tests will be run");
    private static Set<String> tagsThatMustBeIncluded = new HashSet<>();

    public static void setMustIncludeTags(final Set<String> tagsThatMustBeIncluded) {
        ExcludeTagsCondition.tagsThatMustBeIncluded = new HashSet<>(tagsThatMustBeIncluded);
    }

    @Override
    public ConditionEvaluationResult evaluateExecutionCondition(
            ExtensionContext context) {
        final AnnotatedElement element = context
                .getElement()
                .orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new);
        final Optional<Set<String>> tagsToExclude = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(
                        context.getRequiredTestClass(),
                        ExcludeTags.class
                )
                .map(a ->
                        Arrays.stream(a.value())
                                .filter(t -> !tagsThatMustBeIncluded.contains(t))
                                .collect(Collectors.toSet())
                );
        if (tagsToExclude.isEmpty() || tagsToExclude.get().stream()
                .allMatch(s -> (s == null) || s.trim().isEmpty())) {
            return ENABLED_IF_EXCLUDE_TAG_IS_INVALID;
        }
        final Optional<String> tag = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(element, Tag.class)
                .map(Tag::value);
        if (tagsToExclude.get().contains(tag.map(String::trim).orElse(""))) {
            return ConditionEvaluationResult
                    .disabled(String.format(
                            "test method \"%s\" has tag \"%s\" which is on the @ExcludeTags list \"[%s]\", test will be skipped",
                            (element instanceof Method) ? ((Method) element).getName()
                                    : element.getClass().getSimpleName(),
                            tag.get(),
                            String.join(",", tagsToExclude.get())
                    ));
        }
        return ConditionEvaluationResult.enabled(
                String.format(
                        "test method \"%s\" has tag \"%s\" which is not on the @ExcludeTags list \"[%s]\", test will be run",
                        (element instanceof Method) ? ((Method) element).getName()
                                : element.getClass().getSimpleName(),
                        tag.orElse("<no tag present>"),
                        String.join(",", tagsToExclude.get())
                ));
     }
   }
```

Comment: You can use the delegate pattern to create a `WebDriver` that isn't instantiated until it is actually used. See the `LazyWebDriver` here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67724604/how-to-design-a-cucumber-selenium-framework-without-using-static-instances-of-th/67729493#67729493